# adding a row to a Spark dataframe takes long time for processing

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hiveql, hadoop2

I am doing a set of transformation to join few tables in spark to get a Dataframe in spark (name: resultDataset which has 250 columns (250 Million records)).
Now I have to create 4 ROWS (aggregate the amounts. these rows has 4 cloumns each) based on a calculated column from my resulDataframe. After creating the rows I have to add these 4 ( 4 columns) rows to the resultDataframe to get final dataFrame (250 million + 4 rows) and write into HDFS.

I am using a SPARK UDF to append the addition columns with NULL values to the 4 rows so that I will get a dataframe of 250 columns for the 4 rows and then do a union with the resultDataframe to get my final Dataframe which I am persisting as a Parquet file on HDFS using the Hive (insert query)

For all the transformations to create the resultDataframe it takes 3 minutes but to create the 4 rows and add it to the resultDataframe to get my final Dataframe 
it is taking additional 8 minutes. So as a result the total time taken to complete the process is 11 to 12 minutes.

Even if I don't use this UDF rather create a Dataframe with select statement where additional columns are set as NULL for the 4 row dataframe, I still get the same delayed amount of time (11 to 12 minutes).

Is there any way the addition of rows to the result dataframe can be optimised and the amount of time taken for processing can be reduced.

the same use case when done in Oracle (same volume of data and same transformation) takes less than 2 minutes to process and return the data.

Comment: Can you please share the code that you are trying?The one with the Select statement? Also delay in UDF's is understandable as there would an overhead of serializing and deserializing.

Comment: val newValue = previousDF(with the transformation to get the rows).withcolumn("otherCol1", lit("NULL").withColun("otherColumn2", lit("NULL").... all the remaining 250 columns.